# More efficient way to merge columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

My code calculates the euclidean distance between all points in a set of samples I have.  What I want to know is in general this the most efficient way to perform some operation between all elements in a set and then plot them, for instance to make a correlation matrix.

The index of samples is used to initialize the dataframe and provide labels.  Then the 3d coordinates are provided as tuples in three_D_coordinate_tuple_list but this could easily be any measurement and then the variable distance could be any operation.  I'm curious about finding a more efficient solution to making each column and then merging them again using pandas or numpy.  Am I clogging up any memory with my solution?  How can I make this cleaner?

```
def euclidean_distance_matrix_maker(three_D_coordinate_tuple_list, index_of_samples):
#list of tuples
#well_id or index as series or list

n=len(three_D_coordinate_tuple_list)
distance_matrix_df=pd.DataFrame(index_of_samples)    

for i in range(0, n):
    column=[]
    #iterates through all elemetns calculates distance vs this element
    for j in range(0, n):
        distance=euclidean_dist_threeD_for_tuples( three_D_coordinate_tuple_list[i],
                                         three_D_coordinate_tuple_list[j])
        column.append(distance)
    #adds euclidean distance to a list which overwrites old data frame then 
    #is appeneded with concat column wise to output matrix
    new_column=pd.DataFrame(column)
    distance_matrix_df=pd.concat([distance_matrix_df, new_column], axis=1)

distance_matrix_df=distance_matrix_df.set_index(distance_matrix_df.iloc[:,0])
distance_matrix_df=distance_matrix_df.iloc[:,1:]
distance_matrix_df.columns=distance_matrix_df.index
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Setup

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])
```

---

#### `scipy.spatial.distance_matrix`

```
from scipy.spatial import distance_matrix

distance_matrix(x, x)

array([[ 0.        ,  5.19615242, 10.39230485],
       [ 5.19615242,  0.        ,  5.19615242],
       [10.39230485,  5.19615242,  0.        ]])
```

---

#### Numpy

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import squareform

i, j = np.triu_indices(len(x), 1)
((x[i] - x[j]) ** 2).sum(-1) ** .5

array([ 5.19615242, 10.39230485,  5.19615242])
```

Which we can make into a square form with `squareform`

```
squareform(((x[i] - x[j]) ** 2).sum(-1) ** .5)

array([[ 0.        ,  5.19615242, 10.39230485],
       [ 5.19615242,  0.        ,  5.19615242],
       [10.39230485,  5.19615242,  0.        ]])
```

Comment: Thanks but for my purposes. I want to be able to retain the original index so I can compare measures.  In this case I am comparing euclidean distance to correlation of another measure, so when distance_matrix(x,x) computes it loses the information needed to compare the data points.